# CRONJOB - Crontab command not working ubuntu

Tags: shell, cron, apache-zookeeper

Hi Everyone,

Currently in my project we are using Spark zookeeper Kafka Storm Eagle in Aws instance. Suddenly all the services will go down. So we identified the issue and found that zookeeper occupies more space.

```
sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -40
5070384 /tmp/zookeeper/version-2
5070392 /tmp/zookeeper
5095832 /tmp

root@ip:/tmp/zookeeper/version-2# ls -ltr
total 5071368
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     137034 Dec  5 13:23 snapshot.38c1b0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1946157072 Dec  6 05:41 log.38c1b2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     137621 Dec  6 05:41 snapshot.3a206a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2080374800 Dec  6 23:03 log.3a206c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     136887 Dec  6 23:03 snapshot.3b9608
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1342177296 Dec  7 10:02 log.3b960a
```

In order to clear the the above location i have used below command
    zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 3. 
    It works perfectly.

So we have decided to automate the process. Created a shell script file zkClean.sh which has root permission.

```
root@ip:/home# ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       22928 Nov 22 06:50 zookeeper.out
**-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          45 Nov 29 07:21 zkClean.sh**

root@ip:/usr/pricchaa/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin# ls -ltr
total 36
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 6773 Aug 23  2016 zkServer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 1065 Aug 23  2016 zkServer.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 2696 Aug 23  2016 zkEnv.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 1579 Aug 23  2016 zkEnv.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 1534 Aug 23  2016 zkCli.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 1032 Aug 23  2016 zkCli.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   1937 Aug 23  2016 zkCleanup.sh**
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat  232 Aug 23  2016 README.txt
```

Fyi - When i execute the shell script using ./zkClean.sh it works find but it doesnt work in cron job.

Also i have created a sudo crontab to schedule it for every minute.

```
root user => crontab -e

# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 */1 * * * /home/ubuntu/downloadS3File.sh
#0 12 * * mon /home/ubuntu/zkClean.sh
    * * * * * /home/ubuntu/zkClean.sh
```

But my cronjob is not running for everminute. Can you anyone assist my that would be much helfpul

Comment: zkClean.sh file location is

Comment: zkClean.sh file location is in
root@ip:/home/ubuntu# ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       22928 Nov 22 06:50 zookeeper.out
**-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          45 Nov 29 07:21 zkClean.sh**

Comment: Shell script file 
root@ip-:/home/ubuntu# cat zkClean.sh 
#!/bin/bash
zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 3

Comment: See the troubleshooting tips in [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info](/tags/cron/info).  Not a programming question.

Comment: Most common issue comes w.r.t cron job is that, we forget to handle directory changes, means when running a script by crontab, it is in user's home location. so need to make sure we changed directory and are in proper path inside script itself. 
one more point, why there is a space before your contab configuration of your script ?

Comment: Hi Jithin, Thanks for your reply. Do you mean to say script file should not be placed in home location or how it is ? Also there is no space in the shell script file.(#!/bin/bash zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 3)

Comment: When i run the shell script, it runs well without any issue. (./zkClean.sh) but when i use the same sh file in CRONTAB it does not run. Checked the file path and permission, everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Issue was resolved. I have used zkCleanup.sh in CRONTAB as below 

* * * * * to/path/zkCleanup.sh /tmp/zookeeper -n 3